# Using scalar values in series as variables in user defined function

Tags: pandas, axis, user-defined-functions, mask

I want to define a function that is applied element wise for each row in a dataframe, comparing each element to a scalar value in a separate series. I started with the function below.

```
def greater_than(array, value):
           g = array[array >= value].count(axis=1)
           return g
```

But it is applying the mask along axis 0 and I need it to apply it along axis 1. What can I do?

e.g.

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15

In [26]: s
Out[26]: array([   1, 1000, 1000, 1000])

In [25]: greater_than(df,s)
Out[25]:
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64

In [27]: g = df[df >= s]

In [28]: g
Out[28]:
      0   1   2   3
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   4.0 NaN NaN NaN
2   8.0 NaN NaN NaN
3  12.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

The result should look like:

```
In [29]: greater_than(df,s)
Out[29]:
0    3
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

as 1,2, & 3 are all >= 1 and none of the remaining values are greater than or equal to 1000.

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the sample?

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, I've added the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet may be to do some transposes (no copies are made, if that's a concern)

```
In [164]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))

In [165]: s = np.array([   1, 1000, 1000, 1000])

In [171]: df.T[(df.T>=s)].T
Out[171]: 
    0    1    2    3
0 NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0
1 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [172]: df.T[(df.T>=s)].T.count(axis=1)
Out[172]: 
0    3
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

You can also just sum the mask directly, if the count is all you're after.

```
In [173]: (df.T>=s).sum(axis=0)
Out[173]: 
0    3
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this, but was hoping there was some inherent method using the defined function, like changing the axis of the counting or something. I would like to learn how to control these parameters to have more flexibility in the future.

Comment: You can use `apply` to get the mask to be applied on the right axis. *e.g.* `df[df.apply(lambda r: r >=s)].count(axis=1)`, but the transpose and the sum is about 2x as fast for me.